# Can chrome extension content scripts load images regardless of host's Content Security Policy?

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have created a Chrome extension with MV3.  One of my content scripts pops up an image (a web_accessible_resource) when a user is on two specific sites.  The img loads fine on site #1, but not on site #2. If I inspect site #2 in devtools and manually change my img src (to "chrome-extension://file1.png"), the html source code for the img src immediately changes to "unknown".  If I repeat this edit and make the img-src to be an image off of the same domain as site #2, the src changes successfully (it does not become "unknown"), which makes me think it must be a CSP-related issue. But there are no errors that I can see, so I cannot confirm this conclusion.  Here's my manifest.json:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "images/myimage.png"],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*","https://*/*" ]
    }
  ],
```

And the code I use in my content script to create the image and assign the src:

```
let iconImage = new Image();
                iconImage.className="myImageClass";
                iconImage.src=chrome.runtime.getURL("/images/myimage.png");
```

This successfully loads the image when my content script runs on Site #1, but not on Site #2. I have also tried loading the image from an external public host, which works fine on Site #1, but not Site #2 (again indicating to me that CSP is the root cause).

Everything I've read about extension resources seems to suggest that web_accessible_resources are exempt from CSP rules, but then what am I missing?

Comment: `sandbox` is not related to content scripts. It may be a bug in Chrome but you need to show your code/[MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, wOxxOm -- apparently I misunderstood the docs, which say that the "extension_pages" CSP declaration is only for pages served up at "chrome-extension://", which my content scripts are not...so thanks, I've updated my question.  And I've previously found your replies elsewhere to be very helpful on extensions and Chromium bugs!

Comment: The code is fine so it may be a bug in Chrome. Meanwhile try using a `data:` URI directly.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks once again!  (Do you want to provide an "answer" so I can accept it?)

Comment: There's no answer yet because we don't know the reason. BTW, try with MV2.